# Why is zero important?

Tags: logic, axioms, foundations

*I am not sure whether this question is more appropriate here or in
[theoretical computer science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/). I leave it to the wisdom of moderators.*

On the [computer science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) I came across the following (possibly
unintended) [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505):

> **is the empty string a necessary concept?**

This reminded me of the fact that [**the ancient Greeks did good work in
arithmetics without having zero**](http://yaleglobal.yale.edu/about/zero.jsp), syntactically (as a place holder, as
in positional number systems) or semantically.

Having zero (resp. the empty string) will of course simplify analysis
and reasoning about integers (resp. strings and formal languages), and
the way definitions and theorems can be stated.

However, I came to wonder whether it changes in any significant way
the kind of results that can be proved, or whether we get essentially
the same theories.

In the case of arithmetics, I guess this would mean that 0 is replaced
by 1 in the nine [Peano's axioms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms), and that for addition, the axiom
$a+0=a$ is replaced by $a+1=S(a)$. Indeed, it has to give the same
theory as the original axiom $a+0=a$ can be proved from the new one if
we add a new integer 0 such that $S(0)=1$. But I am not sure things
are always that simple, and the lack of zero could cause considerable
complexity in expressing other concepts.

So my question is whether this issue has been formally analyzed, or
whether it even makes sense of asking that question. Would the power
of mathematics be impaired (other than in expressive perspicuity) if
the concept of zero were somehow not available (assume that some
church will deal harshly with you if you even only hint at the
possibility of the concept)?

In the case of the empty string, another user asserted that not having
the empty string would change some properties of strings, such as
prefixing. [I asserted](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19505#19567) that it is only a matter of consistent
definitions, and that the only change is in expressiveness (which is
far from negligible).

Is there any text discussing formally or informally this issue? I
would guess it is important, at least for epistemology and history of sciences.

Comment: zero  is necessary not to change something during addition/subtraction,as empty string it is very important because we can initialize  from it some other string

Comment: But I think that PA (formalized arithmetic with first-order Peano's axioms) will work perfectly starting from $1$ instead of $0$. For the practical side ... can be different.

Comment: If you just want your mathematics to count oranges, then you don't need zero. If you want to do your taxes, zero is probably important. If you want your mathematics to be abstract and generally its own universe, zero is a fairly useful concept.

Comment: I don't see how your modified axiom eliminates $0$, as you say you would then define a new integer, $0$, such that $S(0) = 1$.  But that is equivalent to the original axiom.

Comment: As far as I know, Peano's original axioms didn't include $0$ among the natural numbers. Nowadays, people usually do include $0$, but the change is considered inessential.

Comment: @anorton and OP - I still think that (at least for the first-order version) PA can "start with" $1$ in place of $0$. But in this case, we **must** avoid $0$ at all; if we "define" $S(0)=1$ we will contradict the (revised form) of another axiom : $\lnot S(x) = 1$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: In Peano's original axioms there were only a "first number" and a "successor function", and a second-order induction axiom. Defining addition and multiplication (and thus deciding whether the "first number" would behave like $0$ or like $1$) was up to the user of the axioms. The fact that the _symbol_ he used for the first number happened to be "$1$" is formally irrelevant, of course.

Comment: @anorton I reintroduced 0 only to get a proof of consistency between
my two theories (including addition), the one with zero and the one
without 0. Of course, when reintroducing 0, I also have to prove that
¬S(x)=0 which is obvious as 0 is new, and lose the axiom ¬S(x)=1. But
you also lose it when you extend the Natural numbers to the integers.
This is standard. Also Peano's arithmetics is only an example, while my
question about zero is more general.

Comment: I'm not sure that it will works. As Henning says, it is immaterial for Peano axioms if we start with $0$ or $1$. But the *intended* model has a *first* element. If the first element is $1$, we simply cannot perform "one step back" to get $0$, because there is nothing before $1$.

Comment: I try to recap : *(i)* from the "practical* side, I agree with Asaf : why dispense with so a useful invention, dating back around 1.000 years ? *(ii)* from the point of view of "theoretical" arithmetic (formalized or not) we can dispense with the *symbol*, but we **must** have a *first* element. *(iii)* regarding others branch of mathematics, the debate seems to shows us that they don't like our "old friend" $0$ very much...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe zero is not needed at all, in the sense that you get an equivalent structure whether it's included or not.

A little more precisely, if you consider the category $\mathcal C$ of semigroups, and the category $\mathcal D$ of monoids (semigroups with identity) satisfying the condition that $x\cdot y=e\implies x=y=e$ (where $e$ is the identity; note that ${\bf N}$ with addition is in $\mathcal D$, as is the semigroup of strings including the empty string, but there are no nontrivial groups in there), then the two categories are equivalent: you have a functor $F\colon \mathcal C\to \mathcal D$ which, given a semigroup $S$, returns $S\cup \{e\}$, where $e$ is a new element with operations defined in the natural way, and a functor $G\colon \mathcal D\to \mathcal C$ which given a monoid $S\cup \{e\}\in \mathcal D$ returns the subsemigroup $S$, and $F\circ G$ and $G\circ F$ are both isomorphic to identity functors on the respective categories.

This means that a semigroup and en element of $\mathcal D$ are essentially the same thing, as we can translate anything between the two categories mostly seamlessly.

More model-theoretically, if you have a nontrivial semigroup $S$ with two named (or definable) elements $s_1\neq s_2$ (like $1$ and $2$, both of which are definable in the positive natural numbers, or two single character strings, for which you assume you have names for anyway), then it is naturally bi-interpretable with $\overline S=S\cup \{e\}$: you can define $\overline S$ as the set $\{ (s_1,s_1), (s,s_2)\mid s\in S\}$ which is definable in $(S,s_1,s_2)$ where $(s_1,s_1)$ is intended to be the identity, and the operation which makes this set isomorphic to $\overline S$ is definable.

This means that at least for semigroups with two named (or definable) constants, a semigroup and the same semigroup with an adjoined identity are essentially the same from logical point of view. This is problematic only if we really don't want to add constants (but in that case, you can't really say too much interesting stuff anyway), or are working with the trivial group (in that case, you absolutely can't say anything interesting).

In fact, the stuff in the preceding paragraphs (both the “category-theoretical” ones and the “logical” ones) doesn't really need associativity, you can to the same in any set with some binary operation.

In short, adding identity doesn't really make it possible to say anything meaningful you couldn't say without it, but it just might make it a little easier to say some things.

Comment: I disagree with the general contention that, since we can always add a neutral element to a semigroup to get a monoid, and vice versa, thus monoids and semigroups are essentially the same. They aren't. For example, this process does not always preserve universally quantified equations. To see this, pick your favourite [medial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_magma) semigroup $S$ that is also non-commutative. If you adjoin a neutral element to $S$, the resulting monoid will not be medial

Comment: @user18921: If you take a semigroup which is not a monoid, the resulting monoid will not be a semigroup which is not a monoid. So what? I have never claimed that the two are isomorphic (this is rather rare!), just that we can read from one the properties of the other & vice versa.

Comment: Aha yes, that is much simpler example. Anyway, I think the fact that this process does not preserve identities is *very* problematic.

Comment: @user18921: you can adopt it to preserve identities, but then it will not be invertible. Or you can just take for $\mathcal C$ the category of monoids *without* identity. Either way, I don't see how it's really problematic, except how it can make the translation a little confusing at times.

Comment: Thanks. I have to take time to read this (a bit at the end of my rope), but it
seems to look very much like the kind of answer I am looking for. I
would have expected some literature to exist on this issue.

Comment: @babou: I'm not sure, but I think that if there was an in-depth study on this, it was probably quite a long time ago, which would make it hard to read... I wouldn't expect this kind of issue to be mentioned in a modern text in more length than a remark or an exercise. Of course, I might be  wrong. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take on the matter.

Let $X$ denote a set. Then we certainly want to allow empty subsets of $X$. Otherwise, the intersection of two subsets of $X$ needn't exist; furthermore, the maximum subset of $X$ won't have a complement. Basically, getting rid of empty subsets would destroy all that nice symmetry of the powerset lattice.

Therefore, empty subsets are *really* nice. But, what *is* a subset? In category theory, a subset of a set $X$ would be defined as an injective function $f : A \rightarrow X$ modulo some largely irrelevant details. So if we want every set to have an empty subset, then there had *better* be an empty set $\emptyset$ for the domain of $f$. Therefore, the empty set $\emptyset$ is really important.

Finally, since natural numbers are primarily used to count the number of elements in a finite set, it would be better to include $0$ in our list of natural numbers.

There's many other reasons to include $0$ in our list, but I'll leave it here for now.

Comment: I am quite convinced that zero is extremely useful for that and many
other uses. **My question is not whether zero is useful, but whether it is
undispensible**. I am sure the Greeks knew how to remove 10 goats from a
herd of 10 goats, and explain that there was no herd left. Yet they
did not understand zero. Don't you think that your set theory could be
developed as powerfully, certainly with greater effort and convoluted
language, without ever using 0, and possibly even without the empty
set. I do not know how the greeks expressed their mathematics.

Comment: *modulo some largely irrelevant details.* That made me chuckle :)

Comment: @Shaun, full disclosure, I didn't make that phrase up. I think I read it on this site, actually.

Comment: @babou, I guess what I meant was that, from a practical viewpoint, it is so useful as to be indispensable. However, it sounds like you mean "indispensible" from a more theoretical viewpoint, in which case my answer is perhaps not so relevant.

Answer (score 2):

All of mathematics can be done without 0. Many techniques would become more difficult, but it is completely possible. This happens in topology. For instance, to show that the set where $f=g$ is closed in a Hausdorff space, you cannot subtract and set equal to 0, because there is no subtraction and no 0. So you work around it using other properties.

Math is just a way of organizing human thought, so you can make any restrictions you want.

Edit addressing comments: you just make subtraction super complicated. Subtraction is only defined if one number is strictly greater than the other, and all groups are multiplicative. Although getting rid of 1 as well is even more fun.

As for superhuge cardinals, I oppose overfeeding animals.

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you perform subtraction without zero (if, indeed, *all* math can be performed without zero).  Or, for that matter, how you would make an additive group. ;)

Comment: I can't really see how [superhuge cardinals](http://cantorsattic.info/Huge#Superhuge) have anything with arranging human thought. :-)

Comment: Also, graphing is restricted to the first quadrant. Sequences don't converge to 0, they decrease without bound.

Comment: "As for superhuge cardinals, I oppose overfeeding animals." And numbers, and sets, too. Overfed numbers and sets aren't healthy, either for themselves or for one's mind.